# Thorough Introduction to Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you suggest a book that has a thorough introduction to Singular Value Decomposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find Numerical Linear Algebra by N. Trefreten and D.Bau an extremely well-written book. It not only introduces the Singluar value decomposition but explains applications and history.

Answer (score 3):

Strang's Linear Algebra book linked below is where I learned SVD and it wasn't so bad.  I'm sure it's a reasonable intro for one looking to go further.

[http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Applications-Gilbert-Strang/dp/0030105676/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259356043&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030105676)

Comment: Good. I think I know where to find a copy of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This [course](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=17005383-19c6-49ed-9497-2ba8bfcfe5f6) at Stanford covers singular value decomposition in lectures 15-17. The notes are very good, and the lectures are online too.

Answer (score 2):

The [wikipedia page on SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a summary of the section on SVD found in Linear Algebra Done right here: [Singular value decomposition over finite fields?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6987/singular-value-decomposition-over-finite-fields).

I highly recommend the book.

Comment: Axler's book is excellent, but it doesn't go into depth on the SVD. It stops with simply proving that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Parlett's "The Symmetric Eigenvalue Problem" (since computing the SVD is related to the task of computing the eigensystem of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix) as well as Stewart's "Matrix Algorithms" were very helpful for me.